# Compile Error: expecting a map literal assignment, found ',' in nested map put values

Tags: apex, class, map, nested

I am compile error as in subject line for below code. Can someone please help me?

**Apex Code Snippet**

```
for(iterator=0;iterator<(cd.size()/2);iterator++)
    {     
     answerchoices.put(sq.Text_vod__c,new Map<Integer, String[]>{cd[iterator],cd[iterator+2]};
    }
```

Comment: in map we need assgin like `{key => value, key => value}` like this

Comment: what is cd a collection of, and how can you be sure that cd[i] is an integer and cd[i+2] is a String array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your code to

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> copyMap = new Map<Integer, List<String>>();
for(iterator=0; iterator<(cd.size()/2); iterator++)
{  
   //copyMap = new Map<Integer, String[]>();
   if(copyMap.contains(cd[iterator])){
      copyMap.get(cd[iterator]).add(cd[iterator+2]);
   }else{
      copyMap.put(cd[iterator], new Map<Integer, List<String>>());
      copyMap.get(cd[iterator]).add(cd[iterator+2]);         
   }
   answerchoices.put(sq.Text_vod__c,copyMap};
}
```

This my help you out.

Comment: It is fine but only problem is that I wrote the syntax wrong. Can you please let me know how to put multiple strings in the above String[]?

Comment: Have updated my answer. Hope you where looking for this.

Comment: No What I meant was, copy map will have values like ('1',('X','Z')). Now iterator stands for '1' and cd[iterator] = X, cd[iterator+2] =Z. So how to put X, Z in place of that string[].? Key value in copymap would be iterator only.

Comment: Yes I got it try with the updated code.

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to brief the case properly I guess. in copymap I need to put three values. First One the integer i.e. iterator, Second and third one two string values - cd[iterator],cd[iterator+2]. These two string values will be put to String[] part.

Comment: Sorry Have made some more changes to the code, as per my understanding I have updated my code.